# 'Crypto' node.js module: Cannot find package main file for package error

Tags: node.js, cryptography, node-modules

I've installed the crypto module (`npm install crypto`) into my node.js project, but when I launch my app I got this error:

```
Error: Cannot find package main file for package: /opt/PropertyFinder/node_modules/crypto
    at DependecyGraph.resolveDependency (/opt/PropertyFinder/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:199:13)
    at /opt/PropertyFinder/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:117:22
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at collect (/opt/PropertyFinder/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:115:25)
    at /opt/PropertyFinder/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:130:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at collect (/opt/PropertyFinder/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:115:25)
    at /opt/PropertyFinder/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:130:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at collect (/opt/PropertyFinder/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:115:25)
    at /opt/PropertyFinder/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:130:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at collect (/opt/PropertyFinder/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:115:25)
    at /opt/PropertyFinder/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:130:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at collect (/opt/PropertyFinder/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:115:25)
[7:40:11 PM] <START> request:/index.ios.bundle
```

What does it mean? Where do I found the main file for that package?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you intended to use Node.js' built-in [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module.

If so, you don't need to install this via `npm` and should be able to simply `require('crypto')` in your code.

(Use `npm uninstall crypto` first to remove the "duplicate".)

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying the project hasn't included an entry script. It doesn't have either an [`index.js` or another `"main"` script specified](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules) to allow for requiring the package in general.

```
var crypto = require('/opt/PropertyFinder/node_modules/crypto');
```

It just includes two loose modules, `md5.js` and `sha1.js`, that you'd have to require individually:

```
var md5 = require('/opt/PropertyFinder/node_modules/crypto/md5');
var sha1 = require('/opt/PropertyFinder/node_modules/crypto/sha1');
```